# simple calculator using python

Tags: python

Hello I am new to `python`.i am just going through basic python tutorial and making a simple calculator in `python` but its not working.here it is:

```
#calculator program
#this variable tells the loop whether it should loop or not.
# 1 means loop. anything else means don't loop.

loop = 1

#this variable holds the user's choice in the menu:

choice = 0

while loop == 1:
#print what options you have
print ("Welcome to calculator.py")

print ("your options are:")
print (" ")
print ("1) Addition")
print ("2) Subtraction")

print ("3) Multiplication")

print ("4) Division")
print ("5) Quit calculator.py")
print (" ")

choice = input("Choose your option: ")
if choice == 1:
    add1 = input("Add this: ")
    add2 = input("to this: ")
    print (add1, "+", add2, "=", add1 + add2)
elif choice == 2:
    sub2 = input("Subtract this: ")
    sub1 = input("from this: ")
    print (sub1, "-", sub2, "=", sub1 - sub2)
elif choice == 3:
    mul1 = input("Multiply this: ")
    mul2 = input("with this: ")
    print (mul1, "*", mul2, "=", mul1 * mul2)
elif choice == 4:
    div1 = input("Divide this: ")
    div2 = input("by this: ")
    print (div1, "/", div2, "=", div1 / div2)
elif choice == 5:
    loop = 0

print ("Thankyou for using calculator.py!")
```

by pressing `F5` to run its coming

```
Welcome to calculator.py
your options are:

1) Addition
2) Subtraction
3) Multiplication
4) Division
5) Quit calculator.py

Choose your option:
```

by choosing 1 it should prompt for input number but its going back and showing

```
Welcome to calculator.py
your options are:
```

i think it cannot intercept my option `choise` when entered 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5 and going back.what is wrong with it

Comment: please indent your code, its confusing

Comment: Are you using Python 3?

Comment: In 3.x `input` *always returns a string*. `'1' != 1`. I suggest you implement [a sub-function to ensure valid input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
choice = input("Choose your option: ")
```

when you enter choice as `1`. It takes `1` as string but, your comparing string with int.
Simply cast your input to `int`

```
choice = int(input("Choose your option: "))
```

Comment: ok so by putting int(input("choose option: ") it should work?

Comment: you need to use `int(input)` for all input values